# How can I get numerical values of a symbolic system?

Tags: matlab, numeric, symbolic-math

How can I calculate `roll`, `pitch`, `yaw` ? We need to find the numerical values of the symbolic variables `roll`, `pitch`, `yaw`.

```
syms roll pitch yaw
C1i=[cos(yaw) sin(yaw) 0;
    -sin(yaw) cos(yaw) 0;
    0 0 1];

C21=[cos(pitch) 0 -sin(pitch);
    0        1    0;
     sin(pitch) 0 cos(pitch)];

 Cb2=[1   0     0;
     0   cos(roll) sin(roll);
    0   -sin(roll) cos(roll)];

Cequivalent = Cb2*C21*C1i

R = [ 0.8748 -0.4636 0.1410; 0.4779 0.8735 -0.0933; -0.0799 0.1490 0.9856];
R == Cequivalent
```

Comment: R =[    0.8748   -0.4636    0.1410;
    0.4779    0.8735   -0.0933;
   -0.0799    0.1490    0.9856]

Comment: Please do not add information in comments, especially not code. Instead [edit] the question, either by clicking on that link, or on the "edit" button below the tags of your question.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer to indicate that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can just solve the equation system for your variables:

```
res = solve( vpa(R) == Cequivalent, roll, pitch, yaw);
```

However, there is no solution, so I suppose you made a mistake somewhere.

The result will be in variable precision arithmetic (VPA) and can be converted to double:

```
res = double(res);
```